# Weird font rendering in windows/chrome browser

Tags: windows, google-chrome, fonts

recently I've noticed I have sort of "jagged" or "distorted" fonts in my windows system.
[image: This is how it looks on my screen.]

1. Tried it with windows 11 initially, then rolled back to windows 10.
2. Tried multiple laptops/monitors and still the same issue.
3. Tried changing font for the app and it still kept happening , only way when I solve it is when I zoom in. Also when I see the design in Figma , it looks as it should, the font is crisp and smooth.
4. Tried resetting my monitor to factory settings

Comment: Also tried brave browser, same issues.

Comment: Please add a more detailed image - I can't recognize any jagged edges. If it's related to chromium add an image of the desired result (e.g taken from figma, firefox etc) If it's a logo svg - please add a code snippet

Comment: On bottom of the "A" u can see sort of distorted pixels. That will go away if i zoom inside a browser. Also i cant see that kind of behaviour inside figma. There is nothing wrong with the code itself.